# Groovy - is it possible to load binary class?

Tags: java, groovy, groovyclassloader

I have a Java application that uses multiple groovy scripts, the scripts get cached in memory after compilation Using `GroovyShell.parse(text)` method.

Is it possible to compile these script only once and keep binary classes on disk/database?
The following code would store binary classes in `/tmp`;

```
    CompilerConfiguration compilerConfiguration=new CompilerConfiguration();
    compilerConfiguration.setTargetDirectory("/tmp/");
    GroovyShell shell=new GroovyShell(compilerConfiguration);
    shell.parse("println 'foo';","myScript1");
    shell.parse("println 'bar';","myScript2");
```

After running this code i can see `myScript1.class` and `myScript2.class` in `/tmp/` directory, but trying to use above code to load classes AFTER application restart (so there would be no need for recompilation) fails:

```
    CompilerConfiguration compilerConfiguration=new CompilerConfiguration();
    compilerConfiguration.setTargetDirectory("/tmp/");
    GroovyShell shell=new GroovyShell(compilerConfiguration);
    Class clazz=shell.getClassLoader().loadClass("myScript1");
```

From the source code of `GroovyClassLoader` i do not see any way of loading binary classes other than `defineClass(java.lang.String, byte[])` method, which gives a following exception when trying to load classes:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 2901213189 in class file myScript1`

Is there any other way of directly loading compiled groovy classes?

Comment: Other way, you may compile and create jar and add it to class path? Provided script is in the class, i guess

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, simply providing an `URLClassLoader` with the same directory to constructor of `GroovyShell` works as expected.